# UPDATE with CURDATE() doesnt do anything

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query that look like this:

```
UPDATE `shop_product` SET `unchecked` = 1  WHERE DATE(last_transaction_date) < CURDATE()-3
```

When I start him he doesn't affect single row, although there are more than 300 rows that should be affected.

last_transaction_date is date type column.

I need to uncheck all rows older than 3 days.

Answer (score 2):

Use `interval`

```
UPDATE `shop_product` 
SET `unchecked` = 1  
WHERE last_transaction_date < CURDATE() - interval 3 day
```